# error code ELIFECYCLE while running npm run build

Tags: reactjs, npm-build

I have built react app based on fuse react theme it is running fine in the dev environment by `npm start`
but I'm getting error while making production build, running `npm run build` to make a production build but getting ELIFECYCLE error, I have tried all the options like.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fuse-react-app@6.1.4 build: `cross-env 
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false craco build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fuse-react-app@6.1.4 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
```

1. Remove `package-lock.json`
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Ran `npm install`
4. Ran `npm start` and app is working fine I can access the app on the browser
5. Ran `npm run build` getting ELIFECYCLE error

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
"name": "fuse-react-app",
"version": "6.1.4",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@date-io/core": "1.3.13",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "1.3.13",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "5.7.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.7.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "2.5.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.5.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.26.3",
    "auth0-lock": "11.30.0",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "3.1.1",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.19.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "clsx": "1.1.1",
    "cross-fetch": "3.1.4",
    "date-fns": "2.21.3",
    "draft-js": "0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "0.9.1",
    "firebase": "8.6.2",
    "formsy-react": "2.2.5",
    "framer-motion": "4.1.17",
    "google-map-react": "2.1.9",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "i18next": "20.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "jss": "10.6.0",
    "jss-plugin-extend": "10.6.0",
    "jss-rtl": "0.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "keycode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "marked": "0.8.2",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "1.8.3",
    "millify": "^4.0.0",
    "mobile-detect": "1.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "notistack": "1.0.9",
    "path-to-regexp": "3.2.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.1",
    "prismjs": "1.23.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "qs": "6.10.1",
    "raw-loader": "4.0.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "1.3.9",
    "react-autosuggest": "10.1.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "13.1.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "2.11.2",
    "react-compound-timer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.14.7",
    "react-draggable": "4.4.3",
    "react-frame-component": "4.1.3",
    "react-hook-form": "7.7.1",
    "react-i18next": "11.9.0",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-json-editor-ajrm": "^2.5.13",
    "react-json-view": "^1.21.3",
    "react-masonry-css": "1.0.16",
    "react-number-format": "4.5.5",
    "react-popper": "1.3.11",
    "react-redux": "7.2.4",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-config": "5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select": "3.2.0",
    "react-show-more-text": "^1.5.0",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-spring": "9.1.2",
    "react-swipeable": "6.1.2",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.9",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "0.13.9",
    "react-table": "7.7.0",
    "react-terminal-component": "^1.5.0",
    "react-text-mask": "5.4.3",
    "react-virtualized": "9.22.3",
    "react-window": "1.8.6",
    "redux": "4.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.0",
    "typeface-poppins": "1.1.13",
    "velocity-animate": "1.5.2",
    "velocity-react": "1.4.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "yup": "0.32.9"
},
"peerDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
    "postcss": "7.0.35",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
},
"resolutions": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.17",
    "@babel/node": "7.12.17",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.17",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "2.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.25.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.25.0",
    "@yarnpkg/pnpify": "2.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "eslint": "7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.4",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "js-beautify": "1.13.13",
    "postcss": "7.0.35",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "promise": "8.1.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "2.5.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@2.1.2",
    "tailwindcss-dir": "4.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false craco build",
    "test": "craco test --env=node",
    "eject": "craco eject",
    "build-docs": "find ./src/app/main/documentation/material-ui-components \\( -name '*.ts' -o -name '*.tsx' \\) -type f -delete && babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env src/app/main/documentation/material-ui-components/build.js",
    "analyze": "craco build && source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js' --html analyze-result.html",
    "pnpify-sdk": "yarn pnpify --sdk",
    "lint": "eslint"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 3 safari version"
    ]
}}
```

**Node version** = 14.2.0

**npm version** = 6.14.4

Any solution how can I resolve the above error and make a production build.

Comment: Follow these steps & let me know if it works, 1. Delete package-lock.json, 2. run "npm cache clean --force" , 3. npm install, 4. npm run build

Comment: @JayShukla same error

Comment: Still have issues with this?

Comment: @Chris yes i'm still facing the issue

Comment: what happens if you remove `cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` from the build script

Comment: @KeatonBenning yeah even tried that but getting same error

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: @Yilmaz using Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is the using `cross-env` package. Otherwise other scripts would cause same error, too.

FOr testing purpose, remove `cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` and pass `false` manually instead of `process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP`. so your `build` script should be

```
 "build": "craco build",
```

- if it does not work, clean the cache

  ```
   npm cache clean –force
  ```

delete `.npm`

```
 rm -rf ~/.npm
```

then delete `lock.json` and node_modules, and reinstall

```
  npm install
```

Comment: I have already tried the steps that you suggested but getting same error

Comment: @HassanShahbaz can u update your npm modules to the latest

Comment: Yilmaz updating is not option as updating of some of modules can break existing functionality